# Cant position table where I want in html/php

Tags: php, html, html-table

I am trying to place two tables side by side on a web page but for some reason when I try to position them the second one just goes right underneath the first one. here is my code.

```
<html>
<body>

<?php

function specificstat($statname){
echo "<table cellpadding=10 border=1>";
  echo "<CAPTION>".$statname."</CAPTION>";
     for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++){ 
    echo "<tr>";
     echo "<td>".$i."</td>";
    echo '<td>test</td>';
    echo "</tr>";
}
 }

 ?>

<div style="position: absolute; top: 20%; left:10%;">

 <?php
 specificstat("Points");
   ?>
</div>

      <div style="position: absolute; top: 20%; left:40%;">


 <?php
 specificstat("Goals");
 ?>

</div>

 </body>
</html>
```

I have tried using css to position the two divs and that didnt work either. If someone could figure out whats wrong that would be great!

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried closing the table with </table>?

Answer (score 1):

I would use float. This positions elements next to each other.

```
<table cellpadding=10 border=1 style='float:left'>
```

Another problem is you didn't close the table tag. Fix that and it may do what you want.

Comment: Happens to the best of us. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Although inline CSS isn't recommended, this should get you on the right track:

```
<div style="position: absolute; top: 20%; left:10%; float: left;">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
}
echo "</table>";
}
```

close the table between two closing braces set }}